# How to bind onchange event with select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to bind an onChange event on select. but it is not working. nothing happens when i select item. what is wrong in code ??

```
  function onClickPlusAddonsItems()
     {
       $('.plus-addons-items').on('click',function(){
       var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td><select name="sltaddonscategory[]"
                  id="sltaddonscategory" class="form-control" 
                  onChage="getAddonsDetails(this.value);">\n\
                 <option value="">Select Category</option><?php echo 
                 fill_addons_category($db); ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td><select name="sltaddonsitems[]" id="sltaddonsitems" 
                 class="form-control"></select></td>'; 
        html += '<td><input type="number" name="txtquantity" 
                 id="txtquantity" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="minus-addons-items" 
                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm minus-addons-items">\n\
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
       $('#addons-item-table').append(html);
    });

  }

  function getAddonsDetails(val)
 {
    alert(val);
 }
```

Comment: Typo: `onChage="getAddonsDetails(this.value)`. It should be `onchange`.

Comment: Don't use `on*` event attributes. Bind event handlers unobtrusively instead. In this case, use a delegated event handler.

Comment: Please reproduce the issue using snippet on here or http://jsfiddle.net so we can see what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should register `click` event on document `ready` or `winload`.

Following will work.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){            
           $('.plus-addons-items').on('click',function(){
           var html = '';
            html += '<tr>'; // Please note onchange attribute of select tag
            html += '<td><select name="sltaddonscategory[]"
                      id="sltaddonscategory" class="form-control" 
                       onchange="getAddonsDetails(this.value);">\n\     
                     <option value="">Select Category</option><?php echo 
                     fill_addons_category($db); ?></select></td>';
            html += '<td><select name="sltaddonsitems[]" id="sltaddonsitems" 
                     class="form-control"></select></td>'; 
            html += '<td><input type="number" name="txtquantity" 
                     id="txtquantity" class="form-control" /></td>';
            html += '<td><button type="button" name="minus-addons-items" 
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm minus-addons-items">\n\
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
           $('#addons-item-table').append(html);
        });

      })
```

Comment: @BharatKhadodra Please see updated answer (wrapped code in document ready event)

Answer (score 0):

I guessed that your `<select>` is in a `<table>`. If you want to use `change` event, you shouldn't use `click` you should use...um `change`.

The `<select>` that's generated by the first `<select>` needs to have events (click for this demo) delegated to it from an ancestor element (`table#T` in this demo).

If you are using huge strings try using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead they are 10 times better than literal strings.

BTW as a bonus I added the ability to delete rows as well. Check all of the checkboxes of the rows you want to remove then select the "DEL" option.

#### Demo

```js
var idx = 0;

$('.plus-addons-items').on('change', function() {
  var $opt = $(this).find('option').first();
  if ($(this).val() === 'ADD') {
    idx++;
    var html = `
     <tr>
    <td>
<select name="sltaddonscategory[]" id="sltaddonscategory${idx}" class="form-control">
 <option value="IT WORX">Select Category</option>
 <?php echo fill_addons_category($db);?>
 </select>
 </td>
 <td>
 <select name="sltaddonsitems[]" id="sltaddonsitems${idx}" class="form-control">
 </select>
 </td> 
<td>
<input type="number" name="txtquantity" id="txtquantity${idx}" class="form-control">
</td>
 <td>
 
 <label name="minus-addons-items" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger del">
   <input class='chx' type='checkbox'>
 </label>
 </td>
</tr>`;
    $('#T').append(html);

  } else if ($(this).val() === 'DEL') {

    $('.chx').each(function(idx) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      }
    });
  } else {
    return
  }
  $opt.prop('selected', true);
});

$('#T').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    if (e.target.name === 'sltaddonscategory[]') {
      var data = $(e.target).val();
      getAddonsDetails(data);
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});


function getAddonsDetails(data) {

  alert("HEY! " + data + "HI I'M AN IRRITATING ALERT!!!!!! HEY YOU! YEAH YOU! HEY MYSTERY FUNCTION getAddonsDetails() IS WORKING!!!!!");
  }
```

```css
label.btn.btn-sm {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(4px);
  padding: 2px 0;
  width: 30px;
}

.chx {
  transform: translateY(3px);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<table id='T'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class='plus-addons-items form-control'>
        <option default>---------------</option>
        <option value='ADD'>ADD</option>
        <option value='DEL'>DEL</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```